# How to use to two cell identifiers to sort data?

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

com documentation, and I am using the PFQueryForTable method with two different tableViewCells to sort my parse objects when they are put into the cells. I am doing this so when the object returns a blank string I can reduce its height to 0. Unfortunately when I do this it does not run like I want to and the blank cells are loaded into the first first cell, and not the one that I want to reduce the height to.

My cellForRowAtIndexPath looks like:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object{

    BOOL blank = [[[object objectForKey:@"post"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:@""];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    static NSString *Cell2Identifier = @"Cell2";

    if (!blank) {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        UILabel *label;
        label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        label.text = [object objectForKey:@"post"]; //[object objectForKey:@"post"];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        NSLog(@"posted cell");

        return cell;       
    }
    else {
        UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cell2Identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (cell2 == nil) {
            cell2 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:Cell2Identifier];
        }

        cell2.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"post"];

        NSLog(@"posted cell2");

        return cell2;
    }
}
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: Setting the height to 0? That sounds like a VERY BAD IDEA! What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: What you really want is to not show the objects with empty "post" texts? You should exclude those in your query instead

Comment: I accept @Fogmeister. But if you need, you should implement this(- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath) delegate and return appropriate height for your row...

Comment: The problem with setting 0 height is that it will effectively put infinitely many cells on to the screen. If you don't want to show something on the screen then don't put a cell there.

Comment: @Fogmeister So I am trying to take the posts that come back empty (for instance a user hasn't created a post, but the object key still exists in the background) and put them into the second cell, where I will set a height value of 0 to in my storyboard.

Comment: @user3159704 why are there empty posts? Can you not just change the conditions in the query to not get empty posts?

Comment: Well in the parse data base there is the object key for the posts, and it is by default empty. I am using the queryForTable method, and I'm not sure how to put those restrictions on my query. Can you steer me in the right direction to do that?

Comment: @Fogmeister
PFQuery *posts = [PFUser query];
[posts whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:self.myLocation withinKilometers:10.0];
[posts includeKey:self.textKey];
    
return posts;

Comment: @user3159704 please remember to accept and up vote answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, from your comment you are currently creating a query like this...

```
- (PFQuery *)theQuery
{
    PFQuery *posts = [PFUser query];
    [posts whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:self.myLocation withinKilometers:10.0];
    [posts includeKey:self.textKey];
    return posts;
}
```

So all you need to do is add another where condition to it...

```
[posts whereKey:@"theText" notEqualTo:@""];
```

This will stop blank text posts from being sent down.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because the "notEqualTo:" method wants and id, and not a string. is there something that I missed?

Comment: @user3159704 from the docs... https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS that is how the `notEqualTo` works.

Comment: thank you so much you are awesome!!! So the default value for the object keys were "(undefined)" and so the "whereKey: notEqualTo:" method wasn't able to work. However you brought the parse documentation to my attentions and I was able to figure out that the proper method for an undefined object key was to use "whereKeyExists:" So thank you so much, and please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: @user3159704 remember to up vote and accept answers if they solve the problem.